# The name of a particular philosophy

Tags: theology, existence-of-god

I was wondering what is the philosophy name that approves God's existence if this belief brings about peace and calm in our lives.
This philosophy neither accepts the existence of a heavenly creature / entity nor denies it. It just leaves it to personal preference and on how we feel better looking at it.

Comment: Maybe related [Quietism (philosophy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quietism_(philosophy))

Comment: Thank you @Mauro Allegranza, but the link you provided has not mentioned anything concerning God's existence at all! Maybe, you could share a more fitting link!

Comment: Theologically, what you describe is closer to Quakerism. Philosophically, if the goal is to bring about peace and calm in our lives, then Jamesian Pragmatism. In "The Varieties of Religious Experience" William James argues for something similar in terms of psychological value.

Comment: Good point! Just to amplify tour statements @bodhihaer, I'd like to add that my referred peace and calm were figuratively attributed to our lives! That is as you are well aware all feelings are in out minds. So I meant that the philosophy approves such a belief if it could put our minds at peace and subsequently tranquilize our lives. Also, it would be much more constructive and informative if you could provide me with a supporting reference for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though philosophy has understandably no strict nomenclature, according to the emergent terminological conventions, this view can be said to be *agnostic utilitarian* (if you would like to emphasise the presence of the belief, you may add *theist* to 'agnostic'). Notice that this is a *view*, not an argument like Pascal's Wager, and make sure not to confuse utilitarianism, an ethical doctrine, with pragmatism.

John Stuart Mill, the outstanding philosopher of utilitarianism, is an exemplary figure in this line of thought. The following excerpt from [Jose Harris' article](https://doi.org/10.1093/ref:odnb/18711)  for Oxford Dictionary of National Biography may give an idea about his reconciliation of religion and ethics:

> Like his father before him Mill found that the existence of evil made it logically impossible to envisage a divine being who was both ethically righteous and omnipotent; but unlike James Mill he was able to conceive of an 'ideal Perfect Being' of whose existence there was 'enough in the course of Nature (when once the idea of Omnipotence is discarded) to give to that belief a considerable degree of support'.

Note that Britta Martens also cites J. S. Mill as "agnostic utilitarian" in her *Browning, Victorian Poetics and the Romantic Legacy: Challenging the Personal Voice* (Routledge, 2016, p. 5):

> The pervasiveness of Wordsworthian poetics in particular is demonstrated by its imprint on two otherwise diametrically opposed figures, the agnostic utilitarian John Stuart Mill and John Keble, Professor of Poetry at Oxford, member of the Oxford Movement and bestselling author of devotional verse.

A relevant approach with the similar themes, but decidedly distinct stance is *theological utilitarianism*. The following paragraph from Perry (*God, the Good, and Utilitarianism: Perspectives on Peter Singer*, edited by John Perry, Cambridge University Press, 2014, p. 2) may depict briefly their relationship:

> Not only does the history of Christian ethics have within it hints of consequentialism, the converse is also true, for utilitarianism itself was originally a Christian endeavour and its earliest defences were works of moral theology. William Paley’s highly theological Principles of Moral and Political Philosophy remained standard fare on university reading lists for many years, while Bentham’s Principles of Morals and Legislation, published the same decade, was virtually unknown. In less than a century, however, theological utilitarianism had been entirely eclipsed. John Stuart Mill, who took his cue from Bentham rather than Paley, offered a version of the theory associated with deep scepticism towards religion, and whose practical conclusions were regarded as anti-Christian.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the closest you'll get to this in the Western world is [Transcendentalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendentalism). Transcendentalists are technically Christian deists — they hold that Divinity permeates everything — but it's an open-minded and non-evangelical set of beliefs. There are a number of mystical systems around the world as well — Sufism, philosophical Buddhism, Daoism, Advaita Vedanta — that lean the same way as Transcendentalism from within their own religious and cultural backgrounds.